# Can we make event on Outlook calendar, and show on SharePoint calendar?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

Can we **make event on Outlook calendar, and show on SharePoint calendar** 
by `don’t have to copy or drag and drop` Outlook calendar’s event to SharePoint calendar’s event?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible, out of the box.

There are some alternatives you may want to consider.

- Just connect the SharePoint calendar to Outlook and add the event
  directly in there.  For Outlook users - once you are connected it's
  just like working in native calendars.  The downside is that your
  users must manually connect to these calendars the first time.
- If you understand SharePoint workflows (and are using SharePoint 2013
  or O365) you can leverage workflows to connect to the Exchange API
  and add events to Outlook calendars (but not the other way).
- Use a 3rd party service like IFTT (if this than that) to copy entries
  from Exchange calendar to SharePoint (if you are on O365).
- You can leverage API's and/or PowerShell to script a solution that
  runs on local servers to achieve this result.